# How to prove worst-case number of inversions in a heap is Ω(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, heap, analysis, performance

I am busy preparing for exams, just doing some old exam papers. The question below is the only one I can't seem to do (I don't really know where to start). Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Use the Ω(nlogn) comparison sort bound, the theta(n) bound for bottom-up heap construction, and the order complexity of insertion sort to show that the worst-case number of inversions in a heap is Ω(nlogn).

Comment: "and the order complexity if insertion sort" - what?

Comment: That is all they give you. I Copy/pasted the question. But if I remember correctly, insertion sort in heaps are O(n^2)?

Comment: How can a heap have inversions? The definition of a heap prevents elements from being vertically out of order. Do you mean inversions in an underlying array the heap is mapped onto, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of insertion sort is O(n+d) where d is the number of inversion pairs.

Now say you had a set of numbers, which you heapify (Theta(n)) and then perform insertion sort on them. What does it say about the worst case number of inversion pairs in the heap array?

Comment: I think that's the question: what DOES it say? :)

Comment: @|Vlad: Do I really need to spell it out? The smiley makes me think you are joking, but no upvote makes me think you are serious ;-) :-P

Comment: @Moron - personally I figured it out, but I think more details would be nice for the OP. Like what `Omega` and `Theta` mean and how they help you get to the result.

Comment: @IVlad: I presume OP understands what the terms mean as he is preparing for an exam and this is one of the questions in the previous exam! I intentionally left it unfinished as I treated this like 'almost homework'. If OP comes back asking for clarification, I will provide them, but not until they have put in some effort themselves.

Comment: Im going through some other papers now. But I do know what they mean. Thanks, I think I got it now, but will write it out later to be sure. :)